# How do i read and display multiple images within a folder in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, imshow, imread

I have a folder containing 6 images and i want to display each of them in matlab.
the images are saved as image01,image02....image06.

The output of the code is displaying only the first image multiple times. 
what am i missing??

```
a = dir('Example\*.png');
b = 'C:\Example\';


for i=1:length(a) %where a is the path to the image folder
   fileName = strcat(b,a(i).name);
   disp(fileName);% this allows me to see the names in text.
   Image = imread('C:\Example/Image01.png');
   figure, imshow(Image);
end
```

This loop works and does tell me the name of each image 1 by 1 using the disp(filename) so its not a syntax error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: mmm... did you mean to `imread(fileName)` instead of hardcoding the name?

Comment: filename is not an image so it cant be image read?

Comment: `fileName` is not the name of the image file you want to read?

Comment: When i put Imread (fileName); i get the error 'Error using imread>get_full_filename'

Comment: I am new to matlab so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you also have a backslash missing in `b`. What is the output from `disp(fileName)`?

Comment: it displays the name of the images one by one so image01.png, image02.png etc., like i said it works but only imshows the first image multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect it to display `C:\Example\image01.png`.

Comment: yeah that's what i mean, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Ive worked it out! i created a variable for a(i).name and imread that and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the [dir](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function should return all what you need in order to locate your files properly (and rebuild their respective path too), without declaring an auxiliary variable to hold the target path:

```
files = dir('C:\...\MyFolder\*.png');

for i = 1:numel(files)
   file = files(i);
   filename = fullfile(file.folder,file.name);

   disp(filename);

   img = imread(filename);
   figure();
   imshow(img);
end
```

Comment: Ok ill check that out, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked!

```
a = dir('Example\*.png');
b = 'C:\Example\';


for i=1:length(a) %where a is the path to the image folder
   fileName = strcat(b,a(i).name);
   Name = a(i).name;
   disp(fileName);% this allows me to see the names in text.
   Image = imread(Name);
   figure, imshow(Image);
end
```